# Not able to see message in Bluemix IOT Watson Platform Console

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, watson-iot, device-management

I am trying to follow the poc as explained in the below link.Also I have followed the same steps and verified the same.
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/nodereddevice_sample.html#creating-and-connecting-a-node-red-device-simulator

The issue here is I am able to successfully deploy and send/Inject messages from the node-red flow editor.But in my IOT Console I am not able to see my messages in any of the event/Sensor logs.I am getting the below messages only in Connection logs:

```
**Token auth succeeded: ClientID='d:xxxx:xxxx:xxx', ClientIP=0.0.0.0

Closed connection from 0.0.0.0. The connection has completed normally**
```

Also I have made the TLS Settings optional in my Security settings Tab in IOT.
But still facing the same issue.
Please Advice..

Thanks!!

Comment: please provide you 6 character org for the iot service so we can check log for errors.

Comment: If you are still having an issue, please provide the information that @ValerieLampkin requested so that she can help.